# Ubuntu script for postgresql user creation

Tags: postgresql, shell, ubuntu

Need help on creating a linux script that allows me to create a postgresql user with password based on the following variables:

```
PG_USER="username"
PG_PWD="password"
```

Usually I have to do it manually, but need a script based on the following code (include the flags on the script):

```
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser
```

Based on the above code, need a script that allows me to include the flags and also include the username and password variables.

Comment: Not sure that it is possible with `createuser` utility. Consider to use `~ $ PGPASSWORD=123 psql -U postgres -h localhost -c "create role $PG_USER ..."` or something...

Answer (score 1):

```
psql -c "CREATE USER $PG_USER WITH CREATEDB PASSWORD '$PG_PWD'"
```